# Exampels on a Server-Client-Chat applikation on JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, client, chat, server

I have been "googeling" around for a long time for examples over Server-client-chat application, but I can't really understand them. Many of them are using a class and creates the GUI from it, and I don't want to copy straight from it. Alot of examples doesn't either really explain how you send messages from a client to the server and then it sends the message out to all the other clients.

I am using NetBeans and I was wondering if there is some good tutourials or examples that can help me with this?

Comment: Extract the needed code and put it into a App.java's `main`. Also, this isn't a site for asking for tutorials or examples but specific programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes the multiThreading program :) the server has two classes, and client has one. Hope you Like it!

SERVER MAIN CLASS:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int MAXCLIENTS = 20;
        int port = 4444;
        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        // An array of clientsConnected instances
        ClientThread[] clientsConnected = new ClientThread[MAXCLIENTS];

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("listening on port: " + port);
        } catch (IOException e) {// TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = server.accept();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (!server.isClosed()){server.close();}
                if (!clientSocket.isClosed()){clientSocket.close();}
            }

            System.out.println("Client connected!");

            for (int c = 0; c < clientsConnected.length; c++){
                if (clientsConnected[c] == null){
                    // if it is empty ( null) then start a new Thread, and pass the socket and the object of itself as parameter
                    (clientsConnected[c] = new ClientThread(clientSocket, clientsConnected)).start();
                    break; // have to break, else it will start 20 threads when the first client connects :P
                }
            }
        }

    }



}
```

SERVER CLIENT CLASS:

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ClientThread extends Thread{

    private ClientThread[] clientsConnected;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private DataInputStream in = null;
    private DataOutputStream out = null;
    private String clientName = null;

    //Constructor
     public ClientThread(Socket socket, ClientThread[] clientsConnected){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.clientsConnected = clientsConnected;
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            // Streams :)
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            String message = null;

            clientName = in.readUTF();

            while (true){
                message = in.readUTF();

                for (int c = 0; c < clientsConnected.length; c++){
                    if (clientsConnected[c]!= null && clientsConnected[c].clientName != this.clientName){ //dont send message to your self ;)
                        clientsConnected[c].sendMessage(message, clientName); // loops through all the list and calls the objects sendMessage method.
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Client disconnected!");
            this.clientsConnected = null;
        }
    }
    // Every instance of this class ( the client ) will have this method.
    private void sendMessage(String mess, String name){
        try {
            out.writeUTF(name + " says: " + mess);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

AND FINALLY THE CLIENT:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main  
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       Main m = new Main();
       m.connect();
   }

   public void connect() throws IOException{
     //declare a scanner so we can write a message
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


       // localhost ip
       String ip = "127.0.0.1";
       int port = 4444;
       Socket socket = null;

       System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
       String name = keyboard.nextLine();

       try {

       //connect
       socket = new Socket(ip, port);

       //initialize streams
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
       DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

       //start a thread which will start listening for messages
       new ReceiveMessage(in).start();

       // send the name to the server!
       out.writeUTF(name);

       while (true){
           //Write messages :)
           String message = keyboard.nextLine();
           out.writeUTF(message);
       }

       }
       catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
            if (!socket.isClosed()){socket.close();}
       }
   }

   class ReceiveMessage extends Thread{

       DataInputStream in;

       ReceiveMessage(DataInputStream in){
           this.in = in;
       }

       public void run(){
           String message;
           while (true){
               try {
                    message = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(message);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

           }
       }

   }

}
```

I ran the server in eclipse, and started two clients from the CMD, looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot!! Hopefully I will understand more with this and how it works with multi-threads! Thanks alot for spending time doing this. I will do this one, then try implementing GUI to it! Thanks again, you rock!!

Comment: Sounds as a good idea ! You are welcome :)

Comment: I've tried to find a way to send PM but I couldn't find how to do it so I will have to ask here. In the first Class Server (that is called main) In the for-loop You check if there is a client in the array, and if it isn't then you just create one. Shouldn't you create and add a client in the list everytime a socket gets accepted? Cause to me it looks like the server can only accept one client.

Comment: @Bojje as you can see the serversocket is created first, and after that there is a while-loop. So when somebody connects , it will jump down to the for-loop and check if there is one empty element in the array. And if it is empty, a new instance of the class ClientThread is being created and then stored in the array "clientsConnected[c]", and start it. All in the same line :). And after that, since all this is in a while loop, it will go back to the beginning of the while-loop which is, clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); . And this will go on and on :)

Comment: Yeah that is also something I don't really understand. It's in a while-loop so shouldn't it keep running all the time while it is true? Why does it jump to the for-loop if the serversocket accepts a new socket? And how does it work when a second client gets accepted? Then the for-loop doesn't do anything? EDIT Oh nevermind...I just saw it wrong. Sorry

Comment: @Bojje  the line "clientsocket = server.accept" means that it will wait for a client to connect, and when somebody connects, it will continue to the for-loop and check if clientsConnected[c] is null. Because the clientsocket accept line and the for-loop are both in the while true loop. So when the server has started a new thread, it reaches the end of the while loop. But since it is a while true loop, it will go back to the beginning of the while true, and keep on listening for connections.

Comment: @Bojje makes any sence?;)

Comment: Yes I just missed that the for-loop and server.accept was in the same while-loop :) But after 1 client connects, then there is 1 element in the ClientThread[]. Then the if-statement should be false and not create a new instance of ClientThread class right? EDIT meaning that if a second socket get accepted you don't create a new instance?

Comment: @Bojje If we say like this: 1. server starts and listens for clients. 2. one client connects, which means that the clientConnected[0] will be created. and that is an instance/object of the clientThread-class. 4. server keeps listening. 5. client2 to connects. 6. clientsConnected[0] is not null, because who is there? CLIENT1 :), 7. then it checks clientThread[1], which is empty!. 8. clientThread[1] is created. So both clientThread[0] and [1] are objects of the clientThread-class. So every clients that connects, will have their own instance/object of the clientThread class :)

Comment: @Bojje Yes the If statement will be false the second type, so the for loop has to check the next, which will be empty :) I don't know if you study programming or something but if you have a teacher, I believe he will explain it better than me x) But you have started studying object oriented programming?

Comment: No I have study it like 1-2 courses but very simple and basic stuff, and it was some timeback so this is a refresher for me, but what you are saying makes sense. And I am sitting with fever right now so I might not be at my 100% :)

Comment: @Bojje ook then this can't be very easy for you ;) A tip for learning is to write much code, even it the programs are simple. and use for/while if-elere/switch-case , and learn methods, and then try to work with multiple classes and object oriented programming :)

Comment: Yeah I am actually going to get more into this seeing as I can't really understand this simple code. But 1 more question :) Does the try/catch-statement "freeze" the while-loop untill a clientsocket have been accepted? Otherwise it would just loop and create a new ClientTread object and fill the Array in just a sec.

Comment: @Bojje I wouldn't consider this is simple, especially not for beginners ;) Yes exactly! the line clientsocket = server.accept will wait for somebody to connect, so it will not proceed until somebody connects. Else, as you say, the clientsconnected array would be filled directly :)

Comment: Alright know things are starting to make sense! :) Thank you so much for sticking with me on this one and putting down the time and effort into this. I will come back here and possibly ask more question if I get stuck :) Thanks again for the time man!

Comment: @Bojje No problem just fun to help. When i was a bginner like 1 year ago,, i tried making these chat applications so I thought, when i become better I will help anyone who wants to make one x) You can ask anytime, you are welcome! :)

Comment: Har du skype eller något ? Jag har frågor :). Inte så lätt att fråga genom denna sida :)

Comment: @Bojje sorry för sent svar, har varit upptagen med skolarbete och tenta och skit. Hehe tyvärr har jag faktiskt inte skype. Nej den är inte så bra för det tyvärr. Men det finns chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms

Comment: Sure. Vet inte riktigt hur det funkar men kan man skapa ett eget rum?

Comment: @Bojje Tja hade visst en gammal skype! Har dock ingen vettig mick just nu men går det att skriva meddelanden där ?

Comment: Yeah det går utan problem :) behöver inte mic utan text funkar fint :)

Comment: Om du vågar lämna ut skypen på denna sida :)

Comment: @Bojje hehe arå det är lugnt, men hur lägger man till folk, har aldrig gjort detta :P

Comment: Ge mig ditt skype namn så kan du bara vänta tills jag har addat dig ;)

Comment: @Bojje jag heter "johan" bara :P

Comment: Om du loggar in på skype så skall ditt skypenamn stå högst upp till vänster. Typ såhär  "Skype™ - ditt namn"

Comment: @Bojje om du sökerp på "johan9000" så kommer bara jag upp!

Comment: Så jag har addat dig

Comment: @Bojje Okej det har inte hänt något för mig

Comment: Så nu kanske det funkar

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super simple I made just now with some comments of what is going on. The client connects to the server can can type messages which the server will print out. This is not a chat program since the server receives messages, and the client send them. But hopefully you will understand better it better :)

Server:

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Main {

    public static DataInputStream in;
    public static DataOutputStream out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    int port = 4444;
    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    try {

    //start listening on port
    server = new ServerSocket(port);

    System.out.println("Listening on port: " + port);

    //Accept client
    clientSocket = server.accept();

    System.out.println("client Connected!");

    //initialize streams so we can send message
    in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

    String message = null;

        while (true) {
            // as soon as a message is being received, print it out!
            message = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(message);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (!server.isClosed()){server.close();}
        if (!clientSocket.isClosed()){clientSocket.close();}
    }

    }

}
```

Client:

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main  
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       //declare a scanner so we can write a message
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


       // localhost ip
       String ip = "127.0.0.1";
       int port = 4444;
       Socket socket = null;

       try {

       //connect
       socket = new Socket(ip, port);

       //initialize streams
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
       DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


       while (true){
           System.out.print("\nMessage to server: ");
           //Write a message :)
           String message = keyboard.nextLine();
           //Send it to the server which will just print it out
           out.writeUTF(message);
       }

       }
       catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
            if (!socket.isClosed()){socket.close();}
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example :) A question is if I run 2 instances of clients, will they be able to hear each other? Meaning if I run client1 first then client2 second, will client1 hear what client2 send to server?

Comment: You're welcome, Sorry but this server just takes one client, If a server is suppose to handle multiple clients, then you should use multithreading.

Comment: Yeah I have been looking at that. Creating objects of client class and the running them as threads. But I have no idea how to make them listening on eachother from a server.

Comment: Do you want me to post a simple multithreadad server?

Comment: I'm ready in an hour if no problem occurs ;)

Comment: Oh great! I am actually going to bed but I'll be sure to check it out first thing I wake up!

Comment: This was tricky, first time I did multithreading in just cmd and no gui x) I hope you like it ! :)